# ASP.NET hide Panel on requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a simple web page that has few asp panels. I make a search of record from database and these panels are made visible on the page.
but when, say, i enter an invalid value in the textbox to check whether the RequiredFieldValidator is working fine or not, the Error message is displayed. But the Panels that are already visible on the form are not hidden.
I understand, that because the form is not making a post back, therefore these panels are not set to invisible. Can something please guide me as to how to hide these panels if the requiredfieldvalitor throws an error?

Comment: kindly provide some code for your question

Comment: there isn't any code, i am using the RequiredFieldValidator on the textbox only.

Comment: have you tried to using validationgroup property it may be helpful

Comment: here is an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @krshekhar no what shall i do? let me have look at the link

Comment: @krshekhar the panel does not have any property of ValidationGroup. I simply want to hide the panel if the requiredFieldValitor is not valid

Comment: If you want to do some java-script/jQuery stuff like hiding and showing div use custom-validator instead.

Comment: here is a same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093809/how-do-i-hide-a-div-on-the-client-is-client-side-validation-fails

Comment: Here is a similar question I think it will help you<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093809/how-do-i-hide-a-div-on-the-client-is-client-side-validation-fails

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem kindly provide some HTML regarding your requirement.

Comment: @krshekhar my dear, i have a simple problem. I have a textbox (Challan Number), and a requiredfieldvalidator that validates this textbox. On a button click, If the validator returns isvalid=false, then i want to hide one panel on the page that is already shown. I can do it easily on postback through button_click code, however, since there is no postback because of the validator, the panel shows on the page. and i just want to hide it

Answer (score 0):

You would either have to disable `ClientValidation` to allow a postback, or use custom JavaScript. If a visible postback is an issue, you can easily use `UpdatePanels`.

Answer (score 0):

Attach dependent elements by data-dependentClass of validator and place this script below form closing tag

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
           Text="*" data-dependentClass="addressValidation"  />
      <br />
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
      <br />
      <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
      <hr />
      <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" CssClass="addressValidation">
           Rendered at:
           <%= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>
      </asp:Panel>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var originalValidatorUpdateDisplay = ValidatorUpdateDisplay;
      ValidatorUpdateDisplay = function (val) {
           originalValidatorUpdateDisplay.call(null, val);

           var dependentClass = val.getAttribute("data-dependentClass");
           if (dependentClass) {
                elements = document.getElementsByClassName(dependentClass);
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                     elements[i].style.display = val.isvalid === false ? "none" : "";
                }
           }
      }
 </script>
```